# Dynamically update mcOptions options of Cluster Google map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, markerclusterer

Is the a way to update **mcOptions** on click the cluster?

map options can be updated with `map.set('draggable', true);`,

I need to prevent zooming and change cluster icon if cluster have all markers with the same position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i used - when condition is true and zoom should be removed - update options and map:

```
function(){
  if(condition){
         mcOptions = {zoomOnClick:false};
         markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer($scope.map, $scope.markers, mcOptions);
  }
}
```

Not sure that the best way, but at least - working.